# Getting xml namespace prefix displayed only one time

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb

JAXB problem:
when my package.Info is:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.
XmlSchema(
        namespace = "myUrl...",
        location = "myUrl ignoreme.xsd",
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "myUrl/", prefix = "")
        },
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
```

I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRoot xmlns="myURI..." >   
    <other elements....   >
</MyRoot>
```

when I adjust in package-info the line:

```
@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "myUrl/", prefix = "ns2")
```

I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:MyRoot xmlns:ns2="myURI..." >   
    <other elements....   >
</ns2:MyRoot>
```

But I want the ns2 only as below (not in the beginning of every tag:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRoot xmlns:ns2="myURI..." >   
    <other elements....   >
<MyRoot>
```

How to do that?

Comment: If you are declaring that your `MyRoot` element is part of the `MyURI` namespace you either will have `MyRoot` (with *no* prefix) and `xmlns` (without `ns2`) or `ns2:MyRoot` and `xmlns:ns2`. And those two forms are equivalent. The last form is only valid if `MyRoot` belongs to *no-namespace*.

Comment: What is your **real** problem? Why do you need both the prefixed `xmlns` declaration and no prefix in `MyRoot`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im writing test to an excisting system, and the compoany generated the xml to be like that. Im mocking the xml for the test, and if Im not getting the xml like I need I get a test error.

Comment: hot do I make MyRoot belongs to no-namespace?